# How Override the grid customer magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides

I want to delete some columns from the grid also add new others(custom attributes)  and   show the list of customers according to group (i will have two grid according) to group) I added the sequence `module_customer` in my layout module and I deleted some columns and flush cache but no result so please any help !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can remove column using componentDisabled**

```
<item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

Example remove "Date of Birth" field in customer grid. you can remove any field as you want.

You can Override the grid of the customer create your own module. Follow below steps.

Follow below steps:

**File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/CustomerGrid/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_CustomerGrid',
    __DIR__
);
```

**File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/CustomerGrid/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_CustomerGrid" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/CustomerGrid/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="dob" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date" sortOrder="170">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <timezone>false</timezone>
                <dateFormat>MMM d, y</dateFormat>
                <skipTimeZoneConversion>true</skipTimeZoneConversion>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Date of Birth</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: Fun fact: <argument> must be first tag in <column> or Magento will complain of invalid xml.

Answer (score 3):

You can hide any column which you don't want to display by following

[image: hide couumns]

For add new custom column you need to override

**vendor\magento\module-customer\view\adminhtml\ui_component\customer_listing.xml**

into

**app\code\Vender\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\customer_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
 <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
<column name="custom_attribure1">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your Lable</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">51</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
<column name="custom_attribure2">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">55</item>
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Your Lable</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Comment: i did like you mentionate but when trying to extract a csv file the others attributes come again that's the problem

Comment: for this you need to debug **vendor\magento\module-ui** module

Comment: and how to debug it ??

Comment: you can get solution from this file **\vendor\magento\module-ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider.php**