# How to swap firstname and lastname in customer grid magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer

How to swap firstname and lastname in customer grid  magento 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml` file.

Check the below Link. It may be useful

[How Override the grid customer magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249961/how-override-the-grid-customer-magento-2)

Comment: Thanks for your answer got idea from that

Comment: please help me  same for frontend how to swap firstname and last name in checkout and my account billing and shpiing address form?

Comment: @kanidhaya https://inchoo.net/magento-2/frontend/reorder-input-fields-shipping-billing-step-magento-2/

you can do it database level also,

select * from eav_attribute where entity_type_id = 2 and (attribute_code='firstname' or attribute_code='lastname');

run above query and get attribute ids of firstname and lastname. after that run below query with respective attribute id and update sort_order column value.
select * from customer_eav_attribute where attribute_id = <attribute id>;

I highly recommend to use first option.